# Connection problems - Dreamweaver and MySql

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

(Dreamweaver cs6 – MAMP – Mac - .php )
CONNECTION problems
Can not connect Dreamweaver to MAMP MySql
Error message: ”Your PHP server doesn`t have the MySql module loaded or you can´t use the MySql (p)connect functions”

DATABASES on Dreamweaver have a clear + sign
MySql connection is then entered, but after that starts the problem. 
The first box - connections - will NOT take any signs. (it appears dead)
The other boxes will and I write:

•   Localhost

•   Username

•   Password

•   After this also the first box appears active and so I enter ”connection”

•   Then I click the last box, databases, for options on MAMP MySql, but an error sign comes;

”Your PHP server doesn`t have the MySql module loaded or you can´t use the MySql (p) connect functions”

Have done/checked;
•   DATABASES: All 3 v’s are showing active modus
•   DREAMWEAVER - MANAGE SITE: Server, site, site name and local site folder – all have green arrows
•   DREAMWEAVER: php-pages shows in both code and live 
•   TESTING SERVER: Checked, double and trippel checked that all written info is correct on the Dreamweaver test server info page
•   MAMP: I have made database and tables and they show in MAMP, phpMyAdmin
•   MAMP: Ports 80 and 3306
•   MAMP: Username and password are correct in config.inc.php
•   TERMINAL: Username and password are correct 
•   BROWSER: Pages show in browsers 
•   RE-INSTALLED AND UPDATED: 
o   Have re-installed MAMP, 
o   Re-installed root site for Dreamweaver 
o   When this didn´t work even re-installed and updated the whole Dreamweaver Adobe program

Does anybody know what I am missing?

Comment: You're missing good formatting... this is a strain to the eyes. Please edit your post.

Comment: Can you try with MySQLi ?

Answer (score 1):

Naveed
That is actually a good suggestion for later. I`ll write the "behind my ear". 
I kept on eliminating causes, since nobody seemed to know the answer, until I came to the final conclusion that it was only ans solely due to MAMP. (installed Xampp to make sure Dreamweaver was working) Since it did, I tried resetting my version on php on MAMP (previously set to 7.0.0 - automatically) and made it 5.6.10. That was all that was needed and then it started work!! Hard to know when you have the latest update of Max ox and Dreamweaver and a lot of effort, but.....
Thanks a lot anyway!

global

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set up Dreamweaver CS6 to connect to the database.

The first thing that was missing was the port for the local server. After changing the server url to `http://localhost:8888/`, I faced the same problem that is talked about here, running `El Capitan 10.11.5` and `MAMP` too.

In MAMP's preferences I have changed the php-version to 5.6.10 and I got the connection with no issues, [view the change here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIp95.png).

Now I have no errors and can connect to the database. Thank you so much for your help here. I just wanted to support this solution. There were so many outdated solutions I found on the web. This was posted 6/29/2016.

By the way, are you aware that the server behaviors in Dreamweaver CS6 use deprecated functions that have been removed completely from PHP 7? Even if you get this working now, you will need to replace all your code when your site migrates to PHP 7. Security support for PHP 5 ends in December 2018. The clock is ticking loudly.
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2159670

Happy Coding!